# How to get the Stacklayout id programatically in nativescript

Tags: typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm new to this nativescript.I don't know how to get the stacklayout id properly.I'm working on Angular2 with typescript. I tried below code. I'm getting this below `issue` in command prompt.

```
JS:Error TypeError : Cannot set property 'visiblility' of undefined  Context[object Object]
```

**Html:**

```
<StackLayout #target visibility="collapse" id ="stackLayout"> .....  </StackLayout>
```

On Clicking on the button, I need to show the visibility of stacklayout as visible programatically.

**Typescript:**

```
public stackLayout:StackLayout;

onTap(args: EventData) {

    this.animate();
}

public animate() {

   this.stackLayout.visibility = "visible" ; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you can access the StackLayout programmatically (Google `@ViewChild`), it's probably easier to restructure your code a bit (I'm leaving out the irrelevant parts):

HTML:

```
<StackLayout (tap)="stackTapped()" [visibility]="stackVisible ? 'visible' : 'collapsed'"></StackLayout>
```

or:

```
<StackLayout (tap)="stackTapped()" *ngIf="stackVisible"></StackLayout>
```

Component:

```
stackVisible = false;

stackTapped(): void {
  this.stackVisible = true;
}
```

Comment: hi, do you know how to debug objects in nativescript. console.log is only working for string .But i need to debug for objects

Comment: Have you tried `console.dir(obj`, `console.dump(obj)`, or `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))`?

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)) worked for me.thanks